# Google Firebase concerns and mixing database technologies in a web application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am working with a small start-up which is building a web application. The initial tech stack we had chosen was, a React JS front end, Python on the server-side to handle some external data requests, and Googles Fire-base (real-time DB) as the back-end.

We specifically looked at Firebase due to the documented plugins to the Google suite of tools including google analytics and big query, and the already provided users authentication that comes along with the Google Firebase dashboard.

However since engaging a group of developers, concerns have been raised by them in two areas when using Firebase with our application. Firebase has documented limitations to its depth and complexity of search that it supports.

In that for queries that require complex joins across tables or search criteria that is partial or requires returns of similar or LIKE, Firebase is said to either have no capability or very limited capability.

with regards to users the product is said to have limited capability when building an environment that requires user groups and roles.

It has been therefore suggest we look at moving away from Firebase. Or we consider reducing the use of Firebase to simpler elements of our application environment, moving critical data and data that is found and displayed via complex searching / data queries, onto alternative database technologies that have greater support for data and search complexity.

To that end I am looking to understand if anyone else has their entire web application back-end in either of the two Firebase database offerings (real time db or FireServe) and if you have faced any issues around performance, lack of functionality, lack of capability when trying to do complex things within your back-end.

Then if you did how did you resolve the issue. Did you add on to Firebase with third-party plugins, did you move part or all of your data off Firebase to alternative database technologies, or completely moved away from Firebase altogether?

And lastly I would like to know if using Firebase in a more limited way, for example to manage user access to your application while the critical data resides in another database (for example MongoDB or SQL) is possible or are we over complicating the infrastructure build by leveraging two different database technologies?

Thanks for to anyone who offers their advise. Duncan

Comment: I would *guess* the group of developers you've engaged has a strong SQL background and little or no experience with NoSQL. I only state that as NoSQL databases do not have tables, joins and the queries you run are dependent on how the data has been structured. While the queries may seem 'simple', if the data is structured correctly then they should be - that makes them incredibly fast and scaleable. The question however, is too broad and without understanding the use case, not answerable. I would suggest spending some time getting comfortable with Firebase via the Getting Started Guides.

Comment: Oh, and yes you may be overcomplicating it by leveraging two different database technologies. But. We also don't know the scope of the application.

Comment: Thanks Jay. But the developers we have engaged have a strong background in MongoDB, which is a NoSQL format.  No the issue appears to be limitations with Firebase. Which is why I am looking for comments from developers with Firebase experience.

Comment: If they are NoSQL experienced, what is the specific question? They've raised concerns about *complex joins*? Can you provide an example of what that means? Also, it's a bit unclear what *Firebase has documented limitations* refers to in the scope of your project. MongoDB has depth and size limits as well - 16Mb and 100 levels deep. However, if you're creating a structure 100 levels deep in a a NoSQL database, you're probably doing it wrong (IMO). The question seems to be asking for opinions, which in this context may be ok. However, it's far too vague to be addressed without specific examples.

Comment: Ok Jay. here is an article that outlines one of our concerns https://medium.freecodecamp.org/heres-what-i-wish-i-knew-before-i-started-using-firebase-9110d393e193.

Comment: Ok Jay. here is an article that outlines one of our concerns https://medium.freecodecamp.org/heres-what-i-wish-i-knew-before-i-started-using-firebase-9110d393e193. Disadvantages 1 and 3
My goal here is to simply go into conversation with my external technical team with a base level of understanding, so I have starting point from which to gauge what I am being recommended against. I am not looking for a stick to beat the team with.

Comment: The question should really include a specific description of the issue and the code you've attempted to write to solve it, otherwise it's borderline off topic. I find that linked article not very accurate; the query examples use a poorly formed structure, the info about  location query is just not correct and statements like *incomplete string searches - this task is not possible* is not accurate as I do partial string queries *on a regular basis* in Firestore. Here's a great video with @FrankvanPuffelen on [Geographic Location Query](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q)

Comment: I addressed the linked Drawback #2 in my prior comment as obviously it can be done. Drawback #3 was addressed in my answer with clear code. Drawback #1 is just silly based on the presented structure and then what's being attempted on  *that* structure. The author states *In this structure, it would be impossible to fetch all users who have a friend with a specific name and email.* That's not how NoSQL databases work; the structure is dependent on the query. The presented structure simply doesn't work for *that query*, a different structure would make it super easy.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer but reading the comments shows that one requirement of the post was a partial string query. According the comment, this is the concern

> One user types in “Al” in an attempt to search for his friend “Alex”.
>   You want to fetch all users in the database whose name contains the
>   text “Al” to help the user narrow down his search. **This task is not
>   possible** through Cloud Firestore alone.

So examining that one requirement, let's suppose we want to perform that task; return all users that have a name that starts with 'Al'

```
func findPartialString(startingWith: String) {
    let usersColl = self.db.collection("users")
    let endingWith = startingWith + "\u{f8ff}"
    let query = usersColl.whereField("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startingWith).whereField("name", isLessThan: endingWith)
    query.getDocuments { querySnapshot, err in
        if let err = err {
            print("there was an error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let snap = querySnapshot {
            if snap.count > 0 {
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let key = document.documentID
                    let name = document.get("name") as! String
                    print(key, name)
                }
            } else {
                print("no matches")
            }
        } else {
            print("no data returned in snapshot")
        }
    }
}
```

and would be called like this

```
findPartialString(startingWith: "Al")
```

and the result is

```
uid_5 Alex
uid_4 Albert
```

There are several other ways to perform this same task, so clearly it's not only **very possible** to do, it's also compact code that easy to maintain.