# How to search with space In Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I Want to Search from by firebase database , But When space in between a name then it does not works at all. So what can i do now.. it works before space is given....

Code:

```
stream: (searchString==null || searchString.trim()=='')? 
      Firestore.instance.collection('ebook').snapshots() : Firestore.instance.collection('ebook')
          .where('searchIndex',arrayContains: searchString)
          //.where('organization',isEqualTo: searchString )
          .snapshots(),
```

[image: Here is my Firebase Database]

Comment: Hi, please let me know if my answer solved what you were looking for, thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "space in between a name"? Can you provide examples that do not work as expected?

Comment: For Example say One field of the database contain a string "Frank Van puffelen". Now When i type  Frank in the search box its ok no problem here, but after Frank if i press space then i type Van it will not work in search. I use the code bellow for Search....

Comment: stream: (searchString==null || searchString.trim()=='')? 
      Firestore.instance.collection('ebook').snapshots() : Firestore.instance.collection('ebook')
          .where('searchIndex',arrayContains: searchString)
          //.where('organization',isEqualTo: searchString )
          .snapshots(),

Comment: I am trying to implement full text search with space......

Comment: Please don't post code in comments as it's hard to read; include code in your question. Firestore doesn't have a partial string search so the question is unclear. If your array contains the string *Frank Van Puffelen* and a search is performed for the string *Frank*. no match will be found. Or are you saying to distribute the individual words in the string as different elements in the array? e.g. [0] Frank [1]Van [2]Puffelen? Also you can 'kind of' do a partial string search with creative code using greater than and less than but i don't see that code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following:

```
.where("searchIndex", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchString)  //String comparison
.where('searchIndex', isLessThan: searchString + 'z') //Shows all results until the letter ends with a Z, so this should include spacebar
```

Comment: Good answer, although ending with 'z' is limited. Try `let endingWith = searchString + "\u{f8ff}"` so it would be `.where('searchIndex', isLessThan: endingWith)`From my swift answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866311/google-firebase-concerns-and-mixing-database-technologies-in-a-web-application/55910132#55910132)

Comment: @Jay Thanks Jay thats a better answer :) except flutter doesn't understand the term 'let'. So in this case it would be String endingWith